# Implement DKIM for on-prem SharePoint 2013

Tags: central-administration, sharepoint-on-prem, outgoing-email

*I am a SharePoint guy, not an email guy. Just full want to put that out there up front.*

Client asked is rolling out DKIM across their organization and wants to include all emails coming from the SharePoint servers (e.g. alerts) to be brought into the DKIM fold. The farm does not accept incoming mail -- it pretty much just sends out SharePoint alerts for users that have asked for them.

My searches thus far have come up with solutions relating to DKIM configuration with SharePoint Online and/or Office 365, neither of which apply in this case. In fact, the string "sharepoint" and "dkim" rarely appear on the same page.

Their SharePoint farm is one of those "virtual on-prem" things insomuch as it's running as VMs in AWS and not as a cloud service. Client connects to the farm via OpenVPN. As far as I can tell, the only SMTP pipe is the one coming from the SharePoint Central Admin server.

Not looking for free training here. Just looking for someone to give me any idea of any authoritative resource that might give me directive on where to start. Maybe it's not as big of a deal as I am making it out to be and I am just overthinking it. Either way, can you give a brother a hand?

Comment: do you have exchange in your environment ?

Comment: Unknown, but I presume so. The only client resource I have access to is SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to SharePoint, what you see is what you get when it comes to outbound email. SharePoint has no capability to affix a DKIM signature to email it sends. You can relay through a service (e.g. Exchange or another SMTP service) which can do so, but the SMTP service must simply accept email as-is from SharePoint.